Fatal Exception in Google Play Billing Library: NullPointerException in ProxyBillingActivity
I am encountering a crash in my Android application related to the Google Play Billing Library. The crash occurs when trying to start the ProxyBillingActivity, and the stack trace indicates a NullPointerException when attempting to invoke android.app.PendingIntent.getIntentSender() on a null object reference.
Here is the stack trace:
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.****.****/com.android.billingclient.api.ProxyBillingActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.IntentSender android.app.PendingIntent.getIntentSender()' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3707)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3864)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2253)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)`


Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.IntentSender android.app.PendingIntent.getIntentSender()' on a null object reference
       at com.android.billingclient.api.ProxyBillingActivity.onCreate(com.android.billingclient:billing@@6.2.1:14)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8057)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8037)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1341)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3688)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3864)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2253)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7870)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)

Context:
Library Version: 6.2.1
Android Version: API 34 support
Device Info : 
Attempts to Resolve:
I have checked for null values and ensured that the billing setup is correctly initialized.
Question:
How can I resolve the "NullPointerException" occurring in "ProxyBillingActivity" when invoking PendingIntent.getIntentSender()? Are there specific configurations or additional checks needed to prevent this crash?
Thank you for your help!
Please comment if any additional information required!

I am also facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?

@SagarMaiyad Not Yet found any reason that's why comes in Google Pixel's Device only!

I've seen the same issue. In my case it's only in Google Pixel with Android 12, it's not evenly distributed, it happened for 2 days in July, then it didn't happen again until Sep 28.

@IsidroRodriguez in case it is continues increase in google pixcel devices and also now comes in Billing 7.0.0 + version too
